# Jquery: one call triggered by multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple search page with a single input box.

I want to be able to trigger the search action either by clicking "Go" or by pressing Enter in the input box.  I did it like this:

```
$("input[name='entry']").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        search_phone();
    }
});

$('a#go').click(function () {
    search_phone();
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  Like with bind and trigger, or fling.  If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much can you improve here. Your code is pretty good.

You could skip the anonymous function for the click event.

```
$('a#go').click(search_phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just make your "go" link the submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
```

And then just bind your function to the submit (which would happen either from pressing enter while in the text box or by clicking the go button.

```
$('#my_form').submit(search_phone);
```